# Bash programme for counting characters

Tags: bash

This is the programme I use.

```
clear
echo enter a string
read string
length=`echo -n $string | wc -c`
v=0
cons=0
d=0
s=0
len=$length
while [ $len -gt 0 ]
do
h=`echo $string | cut -c $len`
case $h in
[AaEeIiOoUu]) v=`expr $v + 1`
;;
[BbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz]) cons=`expr $cons + 1`
;;
[0-9]) d=`expr $d + 1`
;;
' ') s=`expr $s + 1 `
;;
esac
len=`expr $len - 1 `
done
spl=`expr $len - $v - $cons - $d - $s`
echo "vowels = $v"
echo "consonants = $cons"
echo "digits = $d"
echo "spaces = $s"
echo "special character = $spl"
```

The program counts all other types of characters except special characters. The output shows a minus value even if there are special characters in the input value. How can I modify the programme to make it display correct number of special characters in the input?

Comment: So you want us to fix bug for you? What have you tried?

Comment: `echo $string` will lose information if the string contains irregular spaces.  Always use double quotes unless you specifically require splitting on whitespace.  `echo "$string"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the wrong variable while calculating `spl`.  Using `len` is clearly wrong as you're decrementing it within the loop and it becomes `0` when the loop is done.

Instead of saying:

```
spl=`expr $len - $v - $cons - $d - $s`
```

say:

```
spl=`expr $length - $v - $cons - $d - $s`
```

Answer (score 6):

While your script is technically (almost) correct, it is not very pretty (both visually and in terms of code beauty).

The reason your version is not working as expected @devnull has already pointed out, but there is another bug that I will explain further down.

Since you are using `bash` you could rewrite the whole thing in a more idiomatic, readable and shorter way.

Here is a rewritten version of your script (comments and explanations follow below):

```
#!/bin/bash

clear
IFS= read -p "enter a string: " string

for ((i = 0; i < ${#string}; i++)); do
        case "${string:$i:1}" in
                [AaEeIiOoUu]) ((vowels++)) ;;
                [[:alpha:]])  ((consonants++)) ;;
                [[:digit:]])  ((digits++)) ;;
                [[:space:]])  ((whitespace++)) ;;
                *)            ((others++)) ;;
        esac
done

echo "vowels           = ${vowels-0}"
echo "consonants       = ${consonants-0}"
echo "digits           = ${digits-0}"
echo "whitespace       = ${whitespace-0}"
echo "other characters = ${others-0}"
```

### indentation

First off, you should always indent your code blocks (`if` constructs, loops, switch (`case`) statements, ...) for readability, e.g.

```
while [ $len -gt 0 ]; do
    do_stuff
done
```

### read, whitespace and the prompt

Since you are using `bash`, `read` is capable of displaying a prompt for you - the extra `echo` is not needed. Furthermore, `read` strips off leading and trailing whitespace which results in an incorrect calculation unless you set `IFS` to the null string:

```
IFS= read -p "this is my prompt: " string
```

### iterating over characters in a string

You can use *parameter expansion* to both get the length of the string as well as slice out one character at a time using a for loop, getting rid of the unnecessary `cut` and avoiding a subshell.

```
# ${#string} = length of $string
for ((i = 0; i < ${#string}; i++)); do
    c=${string:$i:1} # c is set to the character at position $i in string $string
done
```

### character classes

First off, your *consonants* statement still includes `Ii` for the match. Technically it doesn't matter since you cannot fall-through from the *vowels* match, but if this is an assignment you probably want to remove it.

That being said, you could just use the short character class for readability:

```
[AaEeIiOoUu]) vowel_stuff     ;;
[a-zA-Z])     consonant_stuff ;; # vowels already matched above, so superfluous characters don't matter here
```

To make your life even easier, there are so called *character classes* which you can use instead, e.g.

```
[:digit:] = [0-9]
[:space:] = tabs, newline, form feed, carriage return, space
```

etc.
Note that your current locale influences certain character classes.

### the *special characters* case

Just use the default case in the switch statement to count them, then you can skip calculating those afterwards:

```
case ... in
    vowels)     handle_vowel ;;
    [...]
    *)          handle_other_character ;;
esac
```

### defaults

Using parameter expansion you can also get rid of initializing your variables with `0`, you can on-the-fly expand the variables to `0` if they are not set, i.e. they have not been incremented during the loop.

### backticks

Unless you are writing code that has to be super-portable and has to work in all kinds of old shells, use the `$()` syntax in stead of ``` `` ```.

### arithmetic expressions

Same as above, unless you really need it you can use `(( ))` for arithmetic expressions, e.g.

```
a=5
((a = a + 10))  # or even ((a += 10))
# $a is now 15
```

Google and the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html) as well as the `bash` sections of [Greg's Wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/) are your friends.

Comment: Great article! `Ii` :)

Comment: Your answer was very helpful in improving my programme.